# store problem latitude and longitude in realtime Firebase And have the following code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This code is not storing latitude and longitude in firebase realtime database please help me I got stuck in between onlocationchanged method latitude and longitude showing in toast but not storing latitude and longitude in firebase realtime database please help me

> [firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF23p.jpg) JAVA

package com.track_location.tracking_system;

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

public class MapsActivity2 extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    DatabaseReference reference;
    Button btn;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLocation;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2000;
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private boolean isPermission;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    String userid,u1,cust,nm;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        nm=intent.getStringExtra("userid");
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.enable_btn);
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user=auth.getCurrentUser();
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
        ref=reference.child(nm);

        if(requestSinglePermission()){

            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            checkLocation();

        }
    }

    private boolean checkLocation() {

        if(!isLocationEnabled()){
            showAlert();
        }
        return isLocationEnabled();

    }

    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                        "use this app")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int paramInt) {
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(myIntent);
                            }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    private boolean requestSinglePermission() {

        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        isPermission = true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        // check for permanent denial of permission
                        if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            isPermission = false;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

                    }


                }).check();

        return isPermission;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if(latLng!=null){

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker in Current Location"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,14F));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        startLocationUpdates();
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLocation == null) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, msg+nm, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        longitude=location.getLongitude();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ref.child("Latitude").push().setValue(latitude);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Latitude : "+latitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ref.child("Longitude").push().setValue(longitude);

            }
        });
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(mGoogleApiClient !=null){
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of  `nm` in `ref=reference.child(nm);`?

Comment: nm value uid of current user

Comment: Does it work if you change `ref=reference.child(nm);` to `ref=reference.child(user.getUid());`?

Comment: I want to add a node in the existing node

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, the current location is only updated when you click the "enable button".

However, in that code, you are adding a new `OnClickListener` to that button every time the location is updated. Instead you should define the `OnClickListener` to publish the current value of `latLng` (which in the code below I renamed to `mLatLng` to follow conventions).

```java
// Firebase services
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
// Firebase objects
private FirebaseUser mUser;
private DatabaseReference mUserRef;
// Java objects
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
private LatLng mLatLng;
private String mUserId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mUserId = intent.getStringExtra("userid");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser(); // unused?

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mUserRef = mDatabase.child("User").child(mUserId);

    if(requestSinglePermission()){

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        checkLocation();
    }

    final MapsActivity2 self = this;
    Button btnEnable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enable_btn);
    btnEnable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // On click, saves last location to Firebase RTDB
            long latitude = self.mLatLng.getLatitude();
            long longitude = self.mLatLng.getLongitude();

            String pushId = mUserRef.push().getKey();

            Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
            childUpdates.put("/Latitude/" + pushId, latitude);
            childUpdates.put("/Longitude/" + pushId, longitude);

            mUserRef.updateChildren(childUpdates)
              .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                      Log.w(TAG, "btnEnable#onClick:onFailure", databaseError.toException());
                  }
              });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    String msg = "Updated Location: " +
            Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
            Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, msg+userId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    this.mLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    this.mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

If you wanted to save the current location to the database on every update to the location, you would use:

```java
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    long latitude = location.getLatitude();
    long longitude = location.getLongitude();

    String msg = "Updated Location: " +
            Double.toString(latitude) + "," +
            Double.toString(longitude);
    Toast.makeText(this, msg+userId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    this.mLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    String pushId = mUserRef.push().getKey();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/Latitude/" + pushId, latitude);
    childUpdates.put("/Longitude/" + pushId, longitude);

    mUserRef.updateChildren(childUpdates)
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onLocationChanged:onFailure", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });

    this.mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```